# How do I share a Card in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, share, flutter-card

I have a flutter app that is using Cards (within a container). The cards have motivational quotes in them.
The quotes are generated from a database.

We want to have the ability for a user to share that motivational quote with their friends (via Facebook, email, WhatsApp etc). So, it would need to convert that Card into an image - am I right? How could we do this?

As for my code, it is really standard flutter code

Thanks

Comment: share inside your app, facebook, twitter, whatsapp? you need to be a lot more specific... and please show some code of what you've tried...

Comment: I haven't tried anything. Yes, I want to share it in FB or WhatsApp. I can show you my code, but it is standard Flutter...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to convert the quote into an image. You can share the quote from platform's standard share screen. Just use [Share](https://pub.dev/packages/share#-readme-tab-) package from pub.dev.

All it takes is one line of code :

```
Share.share("Everyone wants to go to heaven yet nobody wants to die");
```

The standard sharing options such as SMS, Email etc are shown. And depending on the user's installed apps, they are shown as well. That means if a user has Whatsapp installed then Whatsapp is shown as one of the sharing options.

Note : I don't know if Facebook can share text or not (as in @Chatura's answer). Please check.

Answer (score 0):

From the server-side you can generate an image for your quote and you can use Flutter library [Social share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/social_share_plugin) to share it on Facebook since you cannot share text on Facebook. Whatapp and Twitter you can share the text using Flutter [Share Me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me) Library